# Flow provides null as data from room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

When I use `Flow ( kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow)` I get null as response. Dao  code below :

```
   @Query("SELECT * FROM connect")
   fun getProfiles(): Flow<List<ConnectModel>>
```

**But when I use `List<ConnectModel>` and remove flow I get expected result.**

My connectImpl code:

```
 override fun getProfilesFromDB(): LiveData<List<ConnectModel>>
{
    val result = connectDAO.getProfiles()
    return result.asLiveData() 
}
```

In viewmodel

```
     private val _users = MutableLiveData<List<ConnectModel>>()
     val users: LiveData<List<ConnectModel>>
    get() = _users


 fun getConnectUsers() {

    viewModelScope.launch {
        val response = getConnectUsersFromDbUseCase.invoke()
        _users.postValue(response.value)

    }
}
```

**If I make the _users lateinit then it works fine but not when it is MutableLiveData.**

In Fragment

```
  viewModel.users.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,{list ->
        if (list != null) {
            for(profile in list)
                Timber.i("Observer Active ${profile.name}")
        }
    })
```

**Database**[image]
Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use collect or first like the code below

```
connectViewModel.getProfilesFromDB().collect { 
      //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your code, I've tried it and it's working perfectly fine as it should. It may be how you are observing this live data after getting it. I've this method in my view model and this is how I'm observing it inside fragment.

```
    connectViewModel.getProfilesFromDB().observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ 
          //do stuff
    }
```

Comment: I need to get the value in viewModel and set the value to a LiveData variable Observe in fragment . And I have updated the question with more code, kindly have a look

Comment: What is this ```getConnectUsersFromDbUseCase.invoke()``` returning?